# Stop Duckling from picking the first interval after the given time segment

Tags: haskell, nlp, duckling

Let's say that the date today is the 23rd of July 2019 (which actually is the date of the original post). If we were to process with [Duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling) a phrase like "from January to February", Duckling would link this to the next year: that is, from January 2020 to February 2020. This is because the time segment from January to February for 2019 is already in the past and the following method picks the first interval **after** the specified time segment.

The method that does this is the following:

```hs
runTimeIntervalsPredicate
  :: TimeIntervalType -> Predicate
  -> Predicate -> SeriesPredicate
runTimeIntervalsPredicate intervalType pred1 pred2 = timeSeqMap True f pred1
  where
    -- Pick the first interval *after* the given time segment
    f thisSegment ctx = case runPredicate pred2 thisSegment ctx of
      (_, firstFuture:_) -> Just $
        timeInterval intervalType thisSegment firstFuture
      _ -> Nothing
```

Although I have tampered with Duckling code to adjust it to the needs of the platform, I am not a very fluent Haskeller and this has gotten me to my wits end.

So the question here is: How do I stop this shifting towards a future date range?

Addendum: 
`runPredicate` is also a method and looks like this

```hs
runPredicate :: Predicate -> SeriesPredicate
runPredicate EmptyPredicate{} = \_ _ -> ([], [])
runPredicate (SeriesPredicate (NoShow p)) = p
runPredicate TimeDatePredicate{..}
  -- This should not happen by construction, but if it does then
  -- empty time series should be ok
  | isNothing tdHour && isJust tdAMPM = \_ _ -> ([], [])
runPredicate TimeDatePredicate{..} =
  foldr1 runCompose toCompose
  where
  -- runComposePredicate performs best when the first predicate is of
  -- smaller grain, that's why we order by grain here
  toCompose = catMaybes
    [ runSecondPredicate <$> tdSecond
    , runMinutePredicate <$> tdMinute
    , uncurry (runHourPredicate tdAMPM) <$> tdHour
    , runDayOfTheWeekPredicate <$> tdDayOfTheWeek
    , runDayOfTheMonthPredicate <$> tdDayOfTheMonth
    , runMonthPredicate <$> tdMonth
    , runYearPredicate <$> tdYear
    ]
runPredicate (IntersectPredicate pred1 pred2) =
  runIntersectPredicate pred1 pred2
runPredicate (TimeIntervalsPredicate ty pred1 pred2) =
  runTimeIntervalsPredicate ty pred1 pred2
runPredicate (ReplaceIntersectPredicate pred1 pred2 pred3) =
  runReplaceIntersectPredicate pred1 pred2 pred3
```

Should have also posted the `timeSeqMap` method

```hs
-- | Applies `f` to each interval yielded by `g`.
-- | Intervals including "now" are in the future.
timeSeqMap
  :: Bool
     -- Given an interval and range, compute a single new interval
  -> (TimeObject -> TimeContext -> Maybe TimeObject)
     -- First-layer series generator
  -> Predicate
     -- Series generator for values that come from `f`
  -> SeriesPredicate
```

Comment: FYI, there are no methods here. We usually use the term "method" to mean something that's part of a typeclass. For example, the `Semigroup` class has methods `(<>)`, `sconcat`, and `stimes`, while the `Monoid` class has methods `mempty`, `mappend`, and `mconcat`. What you are showing are *functions*, but not *methods*. As `mempty` demonstrates, there are also *methods* that are not *functions*.

Comment: What do a `Predicate` and a `SeriesPredicate` represent? Does `runPredicate` have any documentation?

Comment: What would you like it to do instead? Pick the most recent date matching the description?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I just the interval from the same. If I am asking for "january till march" in 2019 I want the interval in 2018. Despite it is a past interval.

Comment: That's the second-most-recent. You don't want Jan-March of 2019?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson This was my typo. I meant January to March 2019. I always want the interval from the same year.

Comment: So take the output from Duckling and subtract a year if it's picked a date from next year.

Comment: @dfeuer I cannot really find the definition of the `Predicate` and `SeriesPredicate` ... Unfortunately there is no documentation for runPredicate and there is hardly any documentation for Duckling altogether.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I cannot do that because it heavily affects my parsing pipeline. That is why I'm focusing on Duckling and try to adjust the code there instead.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a big change to your parsing pipeline (just stick a function to fix up the result after your [`parse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/duckling-0.1.6.1/docs/Duckling-Core.html#v:parse) call). But if you don't want to do that for whatever reason, how about setting the [`referenceTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/duckling-0.1.6.1/docs/Duckling-Core.html#v:referenceTime) to the end of last year? Either way, I don't think changing the library's source code is a good idea.